# Can't login with datareader user in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on asp.net project which will be published, so I need to secure my SQL server and give customers login, which can only read data and have permission only to select command.  (I have SQL server which can be accessed remotely!!!)
In local sql server I can connect using this user but when I am trying connect to it remotely I get an error.

```
CREATE LOGIN xyz 
WITH PASSWORD = 'Xyzxyzxyz', 
CHECK_POLICY = ON, 
CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON

GO
USE example1
GO
CREATE USER xyz
GO 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', xyz
GO
```

This is my query in my SQL server. I created user and granted him login, connect to database  engine and datareader privilege, but I can't login with this account to SQL server. Only if I will give him privileges of sysadmin it will work. Another privileges doesn't work. Can someone explain  me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered it by myself.  I just clicked properties of my user -> securables , searched for all objects and added permission to connect to SQL server and it worked!!!!!!!!!!  Thank to everyone for replies!!!!!

Comment: Great, this really helped me. Just adding that you have to search for all objects of type Database and grant permission to Connect on it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to connect your database user with server login. Try this.

```
USE example1
GO

DROP USER xyz
GO 

-- Creates a database user for the login.
CREATE USER xyz FOR LOGIN xyz;
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', xyz
GO
```

Comment: When I am trying to login it says login failed for user xyz.

Comment: try dropping the user first

Comment: It says the same thing:"login failed for user xyz"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44283/discussion-between-sam-yi-and-user2971569)